MS Teams task/modules unable to render frontend service screen
We have created MS teams bot application which contains some UI portion to interact with users, our frontend service is deployed on https://example.com domain which is developed using React JS, and we want to present this https://example.com site within MS teams task/module.
But teams task/module showing blank white screen.
Teams task module with blank screen
We have included example.com in validDomains list of the manifest.json file, but still experiencing the same issue.
Also, we try to set below headers on webserver but it doesn't work for me.
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://teams.microsoft.com/
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com teams.cloud.microsoft

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you please also share the error logs if any using DevTools in your browser?

Could you please confirm that the frontend service screen is iFramable?
